# Javascript function wait fo other one to occur

Tags: javascript

hello Im new to javascript and I cant figure how to make function wait for other one to finish, here is my code:

```
        // other code
        db.transaction(function (transact,callback) {
            transact.executeSql('SELECT * FROM buildings WHERE id = ?', [id], function (transact, results) {
                if (results.rows.length > 0) {
                    buildingsCache.push(JSON.parse(results.rows.item(0).data));
                    index = buildingsCache.length - 1;
                }
                else {
                    alert("Building not found in database!");
                }
            });

        });
        return buildingsCache[index];
        // other code
```

The problem is that current to function returns value before its set in subfunction. I would need to do something like this:

```
        // other code
        var FINISHED=false;
        db.transaction(function (transact,callback) {
            transact.executeSql('SELECT * FROM buildings WHERE id = ?', [id], function (transact, results) {
                if (results.rows.length > 0) {
                    buildingsCache.push(JSON.parse(results.rows.item(0).data));
                    index = buildingsCache.length - 1;
                }
                else {
                    alert("Building not found in database!");
                }
            });
            FINISHED=true;
        });
        while(!FINISHED);
        return buildingsCache[index];
        // other code
```

but its not working. I checked some other solutions here, but didnt make work any of it. Can you help pls?

Comment: Use promises for this purpose. Take a look at `Q js library`: https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your code so the transaction callback is the one that calls the functions that are waiting for it. Basically, your function to fetch the buildingsCache will not return a value. Instead, it will receive a callback and pass it the buildingsCache when its available. This is the same pattern that the db.transaction function uses

```
function fetchBuildingsCache(onDone){
    db.transaction(function (transact,callback) {
        transact.executeSql('SELECT FROM...', [id], function (transact, results) {
            //process db results...
            //then "return" by calling our callback
            onDone(buildingsCache[index]);
        });
    });
}

//and this is how you use it:
fetchBuildingsCache(function(cache){
    console.log(cache);
}
```

Of course, one side effect of this pattern is that every function that calls fetchBuildingsCache and all functions that call *those* functions and so on will also have to be converted to callback-passing style.

Sadly, this is unavoidable in Javascript. The best you can do is use a higher level library (like promises or async.js) or use one of those Javascript transpilers that add async/await syntax to Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Use promises for this purpose.

Take a look at `Q` js library: http://github.com/kriskowal/q

Answer (score 0):

You've a callback in db.transaction(function (transact,callback), use it properly to execute next set of code once executeSql is done.

A promise represents the eventual result of an asynchronous operation. It is a placeholder into which the result will be materialized.

Use it properly callback vs. promise.